# Is there a Windows API function like Sleep() that works like MessageBoxA()?

Tags: c++, function, winapi, pause

When I use `MessageBoxA()` in a function, it pauses the function but the main program still runs. When I try with `Sleep()`, it pauses the whole program, not just the function it is in. Why does this happen?

Is there a Windows API function that works like `Sleep()` but works like `MessageBoxA()`, pausing only the function it is in, and not the whole program without showing dialog box?

I tried to use `Sleep()`, but would like to find another function that works like `MessageBoxA()`. I also tried `WaitMessage()` but it doesn't work as well.

Comment: `Sleep` blocks the thread. a modal dialog won't block that - there's things in windows that change the behavior when one is open

Comment: see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/using-dialog-boxes

Comment: biggest problem is, when the loop ends you cannot reason about the state of the stack, any function higher in the stack that has any pointer or reference to any GUI element is no longer reliable, and any invariant may be lost, surviving the stack rollback to the main loop could get tricky, messagebox can pass because it locks up all the GUI, if you don't lock the GUI then things will get messy.

Answer (score 5):

`MessageBoxA()` blocks the calling thread, just like `Sleep()` does. So, in order for its own dialog window to work correctly, it runs its own message loop internally, receiving and dispatching UI messages. That is why your main UI stays responsive even though the calling thread is blocked.

There is no `Sleep`-like API function that runs a message loop.  You would have to implement that yourself. For instance, by calling [`MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-msgwaitformultipleobjects) in a loop for the duration of your intended sleep interval.  If it detects a pending UI message, use [`PeekMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-peekmessagea) to retrieve the message and [`DispatchMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-dispatchmessage) to let the UI process it, and then go back to waiting for the remaining time left in your sleep interval.

For example:

```cpp
void SleepButHandleMessages(DWORD sleepMs)
{
    while ((sleepMs != 0) &&
           (MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(0, NULL, FALSE, sleepMs, QS_ALLINPUT) == WAIT_OBJECT_0))
    {
        DWORD startTime = GetTickCount();
        MSG msg;
        while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        if (sleepMs != INFINITE)
            sleepMs -= (GetTickCount() - startTime);
    }
}
```

However, a better solution is to simply not block your UI thread to begin with.  Instead, move any lengthy operations to a separate worker thread that notifies your UI thread of status updates as needed.

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much. You are amazing. This does exactly what i needed to do.